# std::thread undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is it possible for the code bellow to produce undefined behaviour?

```
unsigned int total_threads = 10;
vector<thread> t(total_threads);
unsigned int *nums = (unsigned int*)calloc(total_threads, sizeof(int));

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < total_threads; j++)
        t[j] = thread(func_, std::ref(nums[j]));

    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < total_threads; j++)
        t[j].join();

    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < total_threads; j++)
    {
        cout << nums[j] << " ";
        nums[j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It rather depends what `func_` does. As long as it only modifies the value it's given a reference to, I'm fairly sure this is all well defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because calloc may fail. Check for the return value or use std::vector .

Comment: Why can calloc fail? I mean, if there is free memory left, can it fail?

Comment: @Luka If memory could not be allocated, is one example. Your system may decide not to give you the memory for any reason it chooses, though, so you must handle all the possible return value cases. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/calloc

Comment: good point but if every thing can fail, then how to report an error if I can't write to files? What if writing to file fails?

Comment: @Luka: You can detect whether `calloc` has failed (since it returns null), and abort or otherwise avoid using the null pointer. If error reporting fails, then the error won't be reported; but in general you can detect failures and bail out rather than ploughing on into undefined behaviour.

Comment: What does writing to files have to do with memory allocation?